# Windows running application list using Java

Tags: windows

How to get Windows running application list using Java?I got to get the processlist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend also using the qprocess utility, then, if you need more info about a process, use wmic.

Example :

```
String line;
try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic.exe");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
        oStream .write("process where name='explorer.exe'");
        oStream .flush();
        oStream .close();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html or http://support.microsoft.com/servicedesks/webcasts/wc072402/listofsampleusage.asp for some example of what you can get from wmic...

Answer (score 2):

You can run some command line util from Java for collecting processes information. For example:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("qprocess");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Then you just read its output and parse it. `qprocess` is a standard Windows XP utility. In other versions of Windows you probably need some other utility.

Answer (score 0):

you can search SO for similar answers. one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java). See if it fits your needs. Else, there are many solutions on the net as well. search [google](http://tinyurl.com/yh2yeu8) for them

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.vipul;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BatchExecuteService extends Applet {
    public Choice choice;

    public void init() 
    {
        setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 36));
        choice = new Choice();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BatchExecuteService batchExecuteService = new BatchExecuteService();
        batchExecuteService.run();
    }

    List<String> processList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void run() {
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runtime.exec("D:\\server.bat");
            process.getOutputStream().close();
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedrReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputstreamreader);
            BufferedReader bufferedrReader1 = new BufferedReader(
                    inputstreamreader);

            String strLine = "";
            String x[]=new String[100];
            int i=0;
            int t=0;
            while ((strLine = bufferedrReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
        //      System.out.println(strLine);
                String[] a=strLine.split(",");
                x[i++]=a[0];
            }
    //      System.out.println("Length : "+i);

            for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(x[j]);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioException) 
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

you can create batch file like

TASKLIST /v /FI "STATUS eq running" /FO "CSV" /FI "Username eq LHPL002\soft"  /FI "MEMUSAGE gt 10000"  /FI "Windowtitle ne N/A" /NH