# How to clean resource when I interrupt a JUnit4 test in debug mode?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

How do you manage *resource clean up* in *JUnit4* (in a JUnitRunner / in a TestCase) when you interrupt the test in debug mode ?

I use Selenium WebDriver by implementing JUnit tests. When I run the test in debug, if I interrupt the test by clicking on the stop button, then my navigator is still open. I would like to close this navigator by calling a method. But I don't know where calling this method.
In fact, I've overrided **BlockJUnit4ClassRunner** to have my own Runner and I also have implemented a **WebDriverTestCase**. So I can do a lot of things.

I tried to implement *my own SecurityManager* and override the method *checkExit(int status)* but, when I interrupt my test in debug mode, the SecurityManager is not called (with a System.exit(), it works correctly).

Comment: do you know the jvm is exiting?  If it is, you can add a shutdown hook to run custom code when the jvm exits

Comment: It's possible that when you click on the stop button, the JVM running the tests is killed. Depending on the signal(s) send to the process, it might be possible to install a signal handler to close the navigator

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to execute anything, when you stop a debug session.

The only solution to this kind of problem is: Do the tear down in the set up!

This means, you should check in your @Before method, bevor you create a new WebDriver, if an old browser process is still running, and if you find one, kill it. (See [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) and [Killing a process using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java))

Furthermore you probably also want to delete the webdriver directories in your temp directory.