# How to close running process using java?

Tags: java

I am using java Runtime.exec() method to execute bat file,in bat file i have write code that execute jar.This jar contain thread class that pooling infinite time the rabbitmq queue,if message are found then perform operation on that,mean the process will run infinite. i want to  kill this process using java code,also i want know that can this method are able to execute shall script on Linux Os.

```
 **Used java code**

 String myCMD = "cmd.exe /C start c:\\elasticmgmtservice.bat";
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process proc = rt.exec(myCMD);

**used batch file**

cd c: 
cd ElasticMgmtService\ 
java -jar ElasticIndexManagementService.jar config\ElasticIndexManagementService.xml
```

please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: You cannot run a batch file on Linux, provide a specific version or rewrite the batch in Java! To kill the process take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime.exec(...) returns `Process` object which consists following methods

- destroy()
- exitValue()
- getErrorStream()
- getInputStream()
- getOutputStream()
- waitFor()

you can call destroy() which kills the subprocess. The subprocess represented by this Process object is forcibly terminated.
or you can kill by passing `taskkill /PID <process id>` in `Runtime.exec(...)` or `kill -9 <process id>`

Comment: i have try destroy() method but it doesn't close command prompt(process).            String myCMD = "cmd.exe /C start c:\\elasticmgmtservice.bat";
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc = rt.exec(myCMD);
             proc.destroy();

Comment: @sam - i have checked 'cmd.exe /C start mspaint.exe'  is working fine with destroy(). Fact is there some process those are not responding destroy method. it better you close by 'taskkill' or 'kill'.

Comment: @Quoi- when i run the following code with destroy method and 'taskkill' or 'kill' it will not responded, mean it does not kill the process when i try to kill manually from process list it show the java.exe process when i kill this process manually it terminated successfully.i did not understand what happen,if u have any idea please tell me.

Comment: @sam - wht i think is it could be any other problem. can u please try it - Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start mspaint.exe");
p.destroy(); if it does not work then this is some other problem.
cause above code run well in my system.

Comment: @Quoi-i tried but when destroy method called the mspaint windows not closed on my PC and what about your side it closed or not?

Comment: @sam - yes it works in my system. why don't u try in from command prompt or shell.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("taskkill " +<Your process>);
```

In Linux

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("kill -9 " +<Your process>);
```

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea. Using Process#destroy() is much preferable.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec()` returns a Process object, which is an handler for the process the exec method has created. To kill this process, you have to call `Process.destroy();`