# How to automatically kill orphaned Java processes

Tags: java

I've posted this question before, but didn't get the answer I wanted. The problem I have right now is that there are a number of Java processes getting orphaned. This is both on Linux and Windows. I need a way to FIND which Java processes are the ones that are orphaned and kill them.

NOTE: I CANNOT make changes to the Java code as I have no access to it on any level. I am simply running some tests on my machine. I am aware of solutions like this one
[Killing a process using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java/6356410#6356410)
but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear with my question the first time. Most of the responses were regarding modifying the Java code

Comment: So how do you know they are orphans?

Comment: maybe he just wants to delete java from his machine altogether.

Comment: I know they are orphans when I looked at the pstree when the process started. And when I aborted the parent process, the children didn't get killed. And I DON'T want to delete the Java machine. There are other Java processes which need to continue. I only want to delete the orphaned ones

Comment: Where is the other question?

Comment: [try this](http://blog.jonnyzzz.name/2008/03/java-and-process-tree.html)

Answer (score 3):

On Linux an orphaned process becomes the child of `init`, which always has pid 1. To kill java processes that are children of init you can use pkill:

```
pkill --parent 1 java
```

To make this automatic you can add this command to cron, for example.