# Is it possible to kill a process based on process name using java?

Tags: java, windows

Is it possible to kill a process based on process name using java in Windows? The process is not a java process. It is an exe.

Comment: There may be several processes with that name. Do you want to kill all of them, or an arbitrary one?

Comment: Yes! It is.. See my answer :)

Comment: Well, I guess I'm supposed to task this: What have you tried?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6356340/2040040

Answer (score 3):

TRY

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM <processname>.exe")`

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe /T");
```

- `/F` = Kill forcefully
- `/IM` = Name of the Process/Image
- `/T` = Kill any child processes as well

Comment: You just posted a less specific version of something already posted. >.>