# Kill a java process using its Name and not PID

Tags: java, windows, kill-process

In my java program I want to kill a process named "DummyBroker"(which is another java program). i could kill it using TaskKill but it needs PID of the process. So how can i fetch the pid for a specific java process and then kill it?

Comment: `tasklist` will print all processes formatted. You can use this output to search for the right process and fetch its PID. Note that this only works in Windows, but I guess you're aware.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842/how-can-a-java-program-get-its-own-process-id

Comment: As a short term work around i have created a static `Process`. Start the java app using `runtime.exec` and kill the process using `p.destroy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a easy solution [here](http://yannickloriot.com/2012/08/kill-a-java-process-from-the-command-line-or-a-bat-file/)

jps - Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool , can be used for killing a java process with its name.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('C:\java\jdk-7u45-windows-x64\bin\jps -m ^| find "DummyBroker"') do ( taskkill /F /PID %i )
```

We can add above in batch file and simply call the batch file from java program.

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at this link :  [Killing a process using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java)

And use something like :

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM <processname>.<extension>")`

Otherwise you can maybe use a combinaison of `tasklist`and `split` to find the containing line and then find the `PID`.

Comment: This can only kill by taskname. All java programs have java.exe as the taskname

Comment: The java process will be named as "java.exe", above command will kill all the java process not the specific java application(in my case 'com.xxx.java.broker.DummyBroker')

Comment: I can't try it now because I am on a mac, but I will try to give you a more specify  way to do it tonight if no one gives you an answer meanwhile ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM " + TASKNAME);
```

Though this only kills by taskname

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link...http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid

Use `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory` like this

```
RuntimeMXBean rtb = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
String processName = rtb.getName();
int result = 0;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]+)@.+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(processName);
if (matcher.matches()) {
result = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
}
```