# Calling the MongoClient("localhost", "port") method only once using the java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, mongodb-java

I have a tomcat server running my web application. In order to follow the mongo documentation, I need to figure out how my server can always refer to the same instance of MongoClient.

My idea is to create a class variable using the static identifier called

```
public static mongoClient;
```

When my server starts, I would call a method like MongoClass.start() which would make the class variable:

```
public static void start() {
    mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", "port");
}
```

This would allow myself a connection to my database throughout the application. Each time an HTTP request is being handled using javax and jersey, I would make an instance of the MongoClass and do some stuff. Because at the beginning, I initialized the mongoclient variable, any new class initiated will already have this connection to the database.

When the server shuts down, I would call the method MongoClass.close() which does:

```
public static void close() {
    mongoClient.close()
}
```

This would close the thread, effectively handling memory leak issues.
In particular the error:

```
The web application [/app] appears to have started a thread named 
[MongoCleaner1953449629] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to 
create a memory leak.
```

Is my reasoning correct here? Is this a good way to handle the MongoDB java driver?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java

Comment: @Toilal You should flag this question as being a duplicate (flag > should be closed > duplicate of)