# How to close application (stanford: it is a folder consists many programs.) in CMD after I open it? java ProcessBuilder Runtime

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder, runtime.exec

Please know that stanford is not exe. it is a folder consists many programs

I open the cmd.exe by using following statement:

```
public static void runStanfordCMD() throws IOException{
    List<String> cmds = Arrays.asList("cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "java", "-mx4g", "-cp", "*", "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer");
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
    builder.directory(new File("D:/Desktop/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09"));
    Process proc = builder.start();
}
```

so how to close the cmd.exe after I finished some process?

by using  ProcessBuilder or Runtime?
If using ProcessBuilder how to write the statement according to my case?

how to write the statement to the Runtime according to my case?

```
public static void closeStanfordCMD() throws IOException{
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command.exe  /C" + "Your command");  // how to write the statement?

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

Comment: you asked , so how to close the cmd.exe after I finished some process?? but your title question is insane. which program do you want to close , standford folder or programs under standford folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Killing a process using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

> **// how to write the statement?**

if you want to close command prompt:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM " + "cmd.exe");
```

if you want to close stanford.exe:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM " + "stanford.exe");
```

Comment: it does not work.  as my application has its address. the CMD cannot be closed

Comment: Maybe replacing `cmd.exe` with your application name will close it immediately.

Comment: it work perfectly. pls retest and think about your program.

Comment: I doubt it works, and it can be dangerous, because "cmd.exe" is an image name shared by several executing processes. Which one will be killed?

Comment: @LittleSanti, I updated my answers, first time I thought OP want to close CMD as to his sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The method
[Runtime.getRuntime().exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))
returns an object of [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Process has a method [destroy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()) which kills the process you're running.
So what you need is to store the Process object returned by the exec method and call destroy() on it when you want to kill the process.

Also you can call waitFor() method to wait for the process to stop (Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated).

To make it clear, try this code (or modify for your needs):

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -mx4g -cp * D:/Desktop/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer");
    p.waitFor();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No, it can't close the program

Comment: Well, you shouldn't run cmd.exe. There is no need for that. Instead you need to run the application directly with the exec method. For example Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myapplication.exe").

Comment: standford is not .exe

Comment: Since the exec method runs a process, it doesn't need to be an .exe. It can be anything your OS can run.

Comment: I think this solution should work, but the OP must not use `cmd /c start` to run his/her program, but just `cmd /c` (because `start` would create another -unnecessary- subprocess).

Comment: There is no cmd /c start command in my answer. Please forget starting processes via cmd as you will loose the platform independent behaviour of java. And this is the main point of exec method.