# Killing a java.lang.Process not killing subprocess()

Tags: java, process, clearcase

I have a GUI that has many buttons. Each button creates a `Process` (`ProcessBuilder.start()`) that send of a predetermined ClearCase command with pre-set arguments.

After calling `ProcessBuilder.start()`, I add the process to a list. When the program shuts down, I iterate through this list and call `destroy()` on each process. I'm using `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` to try to iterate through my list.

However, when I look in Windows Task Manager, I see that some `conhost.exe` and `cleartool.exe` processes are still alive. I suspect `Process.destroy()` is either not working or not propagating. Is there a way to completely clean up the program and kill all subprocesses when the user clicks X?

Comment: `destroyForcibly()`?

Comment: Are you using a dynamic view and cleartool setview?

Comment: I tried `destroyForcibly()` at first but no change. I'm using a snapshot view just having the process run in the `view` dir.

Answer (score 2):

With `Java 9`, you can kill the subprocess of the main process reference.

```
LOGGER.info("Going to stop the process descendants (subprocesses) {}", this.process.descendants().collect(Collectors.toList()));
process.descendants().forEach((ProcessHandle d) -> {
    d.destroy();
});

LOGGER.info("Going to stop the process {}", this.process);
process.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

see:
[Killing a process using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java)

But be aware that if the process that you invoke creates new sub-processes, those may not be terminated (see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4770092).