# Task manager with Java

Tags: java, windows

Hi so I'm a student in high school and have a project to do with CS. I'm trying  to write a program that shuts down an external application after a certain amount of time has passed. That time part was pretty easy to do but now the problem is the actual shutting down of the problem. I looked around and couldn't find anything that worked for me and need some help with this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TaskKiller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
        String userInput1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hours: "); 
        String userInput2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Minutes: ");
        String userInput3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seconds: ");
        long inputHours = Long.parseLong(userInput1);
        long inputMinutes = Long.parseLong(userInput2);
        long inputSeconds = Long.parseLong(userInput3);
        long hours = inputHours * 3600000;
        long minutes = inputMinutes * 60000;
        long seconds = inputSeconds * 1000;
        long time = (hours + minutes) + seconds;
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time);
            System.exit(0);//was just an idea
            System.out.println("You sucessfully closed the program");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    } 
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.*;
public class TaskKiller {
@SuppressWarnings("IndexOfReplaceableByContains")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
    String userInput1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hours: "); 
    String userInput2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Minutes: ");
    String userInput3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seconds: ");
    long inputHours = Long.parseLong(userInput1);
    long inputMinutes = Long.parseLong(userInput2);
    long inputSeconds = Long.parseLong(userInput3);
    long hours = inputHours * 3600000;
    long minutes = inputMinutes * 60000;
    long seconds = inputSeconds * 1000;
    long time = (hours + minutes) + seconds;
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
 int run = 1;   



while (run > 0){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Program names: chrome, firefox, safari, gta, csgo", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    String prog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Program: ");
    String gta="gta";
    String chrome="chrome";
    String firefox="firefox";     
    String safari="safari";   
    String csgo="csgo";       
    int gt=prog.compareTo(gta);
    int ch=prog.compareTo(chrome);
    int fi=prog.compareTo(firefox);
    int sa=prog.compareTo(safari);
    int cs=prog.compareTo(csgo);

if (gt == 0) {
    if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM GTA5.exe /F");
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(5000);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM GTAVLauncher.exe /F");
        System.out.println("Win");
        run=run-1;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }else if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  sudo killall process PID");
            System.out.println("Mac");
            run=run-1;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
else if (ch==0) {
if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F");
        System.out.println("Win");
        run=run-1;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }else if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  sudo killall process PID");
            System.out.println("Mac");
            run=run-1;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
else if (fi==0) {
    if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F");
        System.out.println("Win");
        run=run-1;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }else if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  sudo killall process PID");
            System.out.println("Mac");
            run=run-1;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
else if (sa==0) {
    if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM safari.exe /F");
        System.out.println("Win");
        run=run-1;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }else if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  sudo killall process PID");
            System.out.println("Mac");
            run=run-1;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
else if (cs==0) {
    if(OS.indexOf("win") >= 0){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(time);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM csgo.exe /F");
        System.out.println("Win");
        run=run-1;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }else if(OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0){
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  sudo killall process PID");
            System.out.println("Mac");
            run=run-1;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TaskKiller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid name. Try Again or quit", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    run=run+1;
}
}
}
}
```

Still needs some working on when it comes to Mac OS. But the windows part works great. Added some video games that i had on my computer to shut down.

Comment: I assume you mean shutdown an arbitrary process, not your program or a process your program created

Comment: Yes, not the program itself just the process like chrome or notepad.

Comment: You won't be able to do this (easily) from Java. You could explore utilising command line commands through ProcessBuilder or using JNI/JNA to connect to the native os libraries

Comment: Here's a question very similar to yours on how to destroy processes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java

Comment: @Raheel138 so what i understood from your post's top comment is that if you start chrome inside of the java program itself, you can then close it to? but if its running from outside the program then you will have a harder time?

Comment: That's what I understood from it. If you're running it from outside the program, you either have to use a native interface like JNI or JNA like MadProgrammer mentioned or you have to make it platform dependent on Unix or Linux. If you run it from within the program, there is only the issue of ensuring there are no processes left running and the fact that all bugs have to be accounted for.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with a solution for macs =)

Comment: so  i tried the solution for macs in school and it compiled but it didnt run. is it possible that it wont run because of the command that it is trying to execute and the administrator settings dont allow it to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `System.getProperty("os.name");` to determine which OS is running the program:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if(os.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
//run windows process kill method
} else if(os.indexOf("mac") >= 0) {
//run mac process kill method
}
```

Then kill the  task based on the OS:

---- **For Windows** ---

You could use the method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` to execute a
*cmd* command in order to kill the process.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Taskkill /IM process.exe /F");
```

Replacing *process.exe* with the filename of the process you want to kill. You might have to run the program as administrator, because taskkill requires elevation to kill some processes.

--- **For Mac** ---

For mac, you will use the same method, just passing different arguments to it. Consider the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  sudo kill process PID");
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c  sudo killall process PID");
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help =D

Comment: my rep is below 15 so its not letting me :(

Comment: Real quick question though. This works on windows but is the command the same thing on macs?

Comment: I got it to work. It just required a few other pieces of code. Thanks for all the help