# How to terminate a specific code block after ceratin time even in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, executor

For example I have some code block which takes more than 30 seconds to execute but I want to stop that if it takes more than 30 seconds. I am trying with executor.shutdown(), executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) and  executor.shutdownNow();  but i can not understand where I have to write my code block which I want to terminate after a specific time. Please give an perfect example.

Comment: You can't do that reliably, so you're going to have to rethink what you're doing.

Comment: Please show your attempt, even if you think it is wrong. It will help to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple: when using **threads** there is no reliable way to kill that thread ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java) for example).

The only choice: start *another* JVM in *another* **process** - because that you can actually *kill*. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java) for details.

Of course - this is rather not the way to go. A better way would be to *implement* your long-running-task in a way that regularly checks for "cancel" commands for example.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go with your methods mentioned, you just add your task to the `executor`, then in the next line of code put `executor.shutdown();` It restricts your executor from taking other tasks and then your actually put `executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to set the "timer" to wait for the task to complete during this time

A simple samle code snipet:

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask());

taskExecutor.shutdown();
try {
  taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  ...
}
```