# How to kill the running port number using java

Tags: java, linux, windows, kill, netstat

I'm trying to kill the `running port(8080)` by using the below `java` code. But, it seems the code is not working.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -aon | find 8080");
InputStream ips = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String value = null;
while ((value = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

I didn't find that anything got printed into output console. And not sure how to proceed further.

I want this code to work on `windows` and `linux` box. Is there any general solution to make this code work on both OS and how to kill the port using `JAVA` ?
Any leads?

Comment: You cannot kill a port. You can kill the application using a given port.

Comment: Refer this answer for making it work on windows and linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6356423/4358787

Comment: Is there any other way to get the pid for the port number?( TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       21448) by the way I can try for killing it explicitly..

Comment: You can try to kill it by executing shutdown.bat file of your server.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan There is no java API to find PID using a port. You need to call windows-native netstat command only to get the PID.\