# How to detect a process is running using python

Tags: python, process, jython

I have to do some task whenever some specific applications were launched. Is there any way to  list all the processes running in an operating system or detect whenever a new process is created in operating system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, there is a bit of stuff in the standard Python library that Jython doesn't implement probably because it's platform dependent and too much work for the small Jython community to implement. Try looking for a [Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java), it's trivial to invoke Java code from Jython.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). Psutil provides information on running processes and system utilization.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Where is that traceback coming from ?

Comment: That means he's running jython and psutil doesn't have support for it.