# How to enum all windows using java

Tags: java, .net

I am using Java in multi-screen environment. I want to enum all windows opened and select one  window to be displayed in one selected screen. What Class or Interface should I use? Anyone could give some guidance.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a cross-platform solution. Do you target a specific platform?

Comment: For this is just a part of one big program which uses Java environment, this little function must be integrated into the main program. You can also tell me the solution for other platform. Thanks anyway! @Arnout Engelen

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)