# Java Program to enlist currently opened/executing applications on windows

Tags: java, windows

how can we make a java program which enlist all the running/opened applications on  a windows machine , i have the requirement to keep switching among the application dynamically.

Is there any java API for window threads ???

Comment: have you tried Google at all?

Comment: yep but i dont get any suggestions regarding the window threads , i can enlist threads only created by my ...... a little push is all i need , just head me to the right direction if u can

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323408/get-a-list-of-all-threads-currently-running-in-java

Comment: whould this help? if not, please, explain more what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

```
public static void main(String[] asss){
        try{
        String line;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                System.getenv("windir") + "/system32/" + "tasklist.exe");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {         
                System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Yes. I used it some where in my application... what is wrong with it...?

Comment: it is just copy past from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java Lets see if it is enough for author or not

Comment: the upper part is identical to the one in the question, adopted for Windows

Comment: You have said you are going to delete the answer. No one can trust your words.