# how to get currently running application names on windows using java?

Tags: java, windows, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)

how to get currently running application names on windows using java? For example only the opened and haven't work programs i don't need,  I only need the current running application name on the desktop. I am doing those. There are connected on the local network computers and 1 server. The server want to know the client computers work on the what kind of programs. Please help me