# Display, Check and Start the linux processes using java code

Tags: java, linux

I am developing an application which displays the running processes in linux and if any of the process is not running start that process. All the actions should be performed by firing linux commands. Also create a log text file and insert the log in the processlog table in database.

Java code sample preferred.
Urgent please.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` is exactly what you need. Take a look at docs -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html