# Getting process Details in windows using Java

Tags: java, process

In windows OS. using tasklist ( [getting list of current open process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) ) i have collected list of running process. But how to get actual path of executable file of that process [FILE LOCATION]?

Is there any way to find recently used process from java?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class taskmanager {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                String line;
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
                    // new lines from here
                       String searchPath = "where notepad.exe";
                       searchProcessPath(searchPath);
                }
                input.close();
            }
public static void searchProcessPath(String processName) throws IOException
        {
             Runtime.getRuntime().exec(processName);
         }
        }
```

Comment: i got the process name, id, seesionname,... but i need the actual file location of that process.

Comment: @Dineshkumar : are you considering windows 2003 and above ??

Comment: @Dineshkumar : give this a try

Comment: IOException: Cannot run program "where": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified