# How to see if program is running in background with java

Tags: java

I'm writing a java program which should work only if one other program is running and not running in background is there any way to check it?

Comment: Do you own both programs? If so, consider having each open a socket and talk to each other.

Comment: Maybe this gives a starting point: http://crunchify.com/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-processes-with-java/

Comment: Probable this post answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005410/check-if-some-exe-program-is-running-on-the-windows

Comment: i only own on of these programms