# How to print a message when a user closes the calculator?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a program in Java which opens the Windows calculator with `ProcessBuilder`. I need to detect when the program is closed by a user, and make a message appear saying "Program has been closed successfully".

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe");
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Program has been closed successfully");
```

The problem is the message appears when the program is open.

Comment: `calc.exe` is probably just initializing the application in a separate thread, and then exits. It doesn't return a handle to the thread it creates, so you can't detect the window closing.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/54686/5743988) will help you detect when the window closes.

Comment: Can you add more information about your environment? I can reproduce the problem, but Rishal dev singh couldn't. My environment is Windows 10 Home v. 1151, with Java 1.8.0.910

Comment: Windows 10 Pro v. 1607 with Java 1.8.0.101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can periodically check if the process is still running using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19005828/5743988), and then post the message when the process is missing. On Windows 10, the process you're looking for is `Calculator.exe`.

Here is a Java 8 way to check if the process is running:

```
private static boolean processIsRunning(String processName) throws IOException {

    String taskList = System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\tasklist.exe";
    InputStream is = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(taskList).getInputStream();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
        return br
            .lines()
            .anyMatch(line -> line.contains(processName));
    }

}
```

And then you can wait for `processIsRunning("Calculator.exe")` to be true.

Here's a quick and dirty implementation of that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc.exe").waitFor();
    while (processIsRunning("Calculator.exe")) {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // make this smaller if you want
    }
    System.out.println("Program has been closed successfully");
}
```

Comment: Its perfect! Thank you very much!