# Process listener and auto key input sent to machine [Java]

Tags: java

I would like to create a program that looks if a process is opened in the system, and if so it sends a key combination (like CTRL+F1/2.. etc) to the machine (on Windows).
I'm more familiar with Java for programming, but I didn't find anything for the keylog problem. I found this: [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) & this: [check if some exe program is running on the windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005410/check-if-some-exe-program-is-running-on-the-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) to see open processes, but I don't know how to set the auto send key combination.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the Robot classes? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Wow I didn't see this class! So if I use keyPress to send auto key combination should work.. I'll test it rn! Thank you