# How to get list of running processes with Java

Tags: java, linux

I want to get a list with all running processes using Java code?. Can you tell me from which file I can get this information? I would like to get his data from /proc filesystem.

Comment: do you mean windows/linux process?

Answer (score 8):

Just parse the input obtained by running `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -e");`

I assume you use linux since you have tagged the question with `linux`.

By the way this one is related: [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)

Answer (score 3):

For Linux,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -e");
BufferedReader processReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
// Read from BufferedReader
```

From windows

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
    BufferedReader processReader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    // Read from BufferedReader
```

Comment: *Note*: He tagged it with `linux`.

Comment: I would like to get his data from /proc.

Answer (score 2):

The numerically named folders in `/proc` contain information on the processes on your system.

Getting the contents of those into a human readable format would require some effort in directory traversal, reading documentation and code related to the `/proc` FS, and is too wide an area to go into detail with here, but concrete issues related to this would be great SO followup questions :-)

Cheers,

Comment: Yes. How I can get this data and format it into human readable format?