# Kill process that is running on certain port in java

Tags: java, kill-process

Is it possible to kill a process using port that it is listening on in java? 
 I know on linux you can use `fuser` command but I would prefer to do it programatically and make it OS universal.

Comment: You can just use that command in any OS you want and run it in Java with the Java process API Link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-process-api

Comment: I suppose It is an option the thing is you have to use different command for different operating systems

Comment: @NLxDoDge No you can't. `fuser` doesn't exist on all operating systems.

Comment: Look how others are trying to get the running processes in java. None of these solutions can check whether a socket is in use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472639/how-to-get-list-of-running-processes-with-java

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri I have decided to use `process.pid()` and save it into databaes since. It causes some other problems that is why I wanted to avoid that but it is the most universal one

Comment: The way we do it is by printing a nice error message saying the port is already in use and where to change the port number if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to use KISS rule and just timeout process my program starts instead of performing dangerous OS commands

Comment: That's the most reliable way since you are handling it in a platform-independent manner.

Answer (score 0):

Call [netstat -p](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat). Netstat will print the pid if you have sufficient privileges.
Next call [kill](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) to terminate the process.

You can do that manually, you can as well script it or code it in Java.

Comment: This answear is great, but It won't work on windows, I want it to be universal.

Comment: Netstat exists on Windows, however the command line option may be different. Also you have to use taskkill instead of kill. I'm afraid there is no platform independent solution here. You also did not specify you need such a solution.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add that, You are absolutely correct