# How can I get the user of a process in Java

Tags: java, process

Is there any way to get the user of a process (as it is shown in the task manager) in Windows using java?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I want a list of all the processes that are running with their users

Comment: You can run `tasklist` using Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder.

Comment: will that also list the user names as it is shown in the task manager?

Comment: As suggested above, try parsing output of `tasklist.exe`. See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java

Comment: I don't think this will give the user name of the process.. I mean PROCESS NAME->explorer.exe  USER NAME->John Doe

Comment: In any case, you need to find the windows command that will give you the information you need as console output.  As such it is not really a Java question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the process owner using this

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

Comment: If multiple users are logged in one system, will it show the users of all the processes?