# Find running apps in windows using java

Tags: java, windows, process

Find running apps in windows which can be seen in task manager under Apps Section. I want java code for getting that particular Apps list. i am able to get whole running background processes but i want **running** **APPLICATION** which shows under Apps tab in Task manager.

Comment: Have you tried anything? First google result for the query "find running apps using java" gives this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java

Comment: JNI/JNA intergration

Comment: i have seen that answer. It shows whole background process. I just need Application running which are under Apps in task manager. How could i filter it??

Comment: You can use the Windows [tasklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) command as described in the accepted answer of [How to get a list of running processes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728351/1782997). Though this command has several options it's unlikely going to provide _exactly_ what you want which means you'll probably have to parse its output and get the information relevant to you from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "qprocess" on cmd --> easy find command on gg ru run on java