# How to get a list of running processes in Java and check if a process is running?

Tags: java, process

So I want to check if "join.me" the program is running when my application opens.

https://www.join.me/

That is the site to the download.

```
Process joinme = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("join.me");
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Any idea?

Or I want to cycle through an array of processes to see what the "join.me" process is called.

Cheers.

Comment: Then you probably first learn about the operating system this is supposed to run on; and figure how you acquire such information there. For sure, not like this.

Comment: @GhostCat I can't figure it out, that is why I'm asking here.

Comment: Your question reads like you didn't do much preliminary research prior to asking. If you *did* do research, please show the fruits of your search efforts with the question. That's likely why you got the down-vote.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, I'll research more before asking next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Microsoft's OOTB `tasklist.exe` utility that comes with Windows and available at `C:\windows\system32\tasklist.exe`. And the following line:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
```

will execute it. Then you can read this string with `Scanner` until it has next line. The following code gives you the list of running programs (foreground as well as background applications) running on your system:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

You'll get the output like this:
[image]