# get process from clients PC and send to server

Tags: java

Through client server socket i have made a connection between client and server and can send and receive messages between client and server now i want to get all running processes i.e. (task manager of client) on client machine and send that task manager  to server machine how can it be done with above socket functionality

Comment: Please specify what kind of sockets you are using. Are you asking how to retrieve all processes in Java? Or are you asking how to send data over a socket?

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement a bit,

Comment: i have 2 machines client and server i have made a connection between them through simple client server sockets chat example , and can get user name/ip address of client machine on server machine.Now i want to send all the running processes(task manager of client machine) to server machine

Comment: from get process code i can get running  process of that  machine now i want to send these processes to other machine how can this be done ???

Answer (score 0):

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) to get a list of all processes.

Then you probably want to turn the list into a format specified by you (a byte array, a string or an serialized object). And send it through the socket. Then read and parse the send data on the server.