# System call Accessing process information like ID, type ect.

Tags: java, windows, operating-system

For my project I need to access process information.
As per my survey their is no any process table in OS.

Is their any system call like

> `proc()`

so that can access related information is process is System process or User process.

If I get that respective information can I do further some implementation for my simulator?

My simulator is implemented in Windows using JAVA it will be better to know in such manner.

Comment: Of course there is, else there would be no Task Manager!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-seopen-windows-process-with-java

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin James