# Get starttime of a process in windows / linux?

Tags: java, process, runtime, jna

I have the ID (pid) of this process.
Now i want to find out when the process with this id has started.

Note1: The process is not a java thread.
Note2: JNA Solutions would also be welcome

From my java context i want to get this information.
How can it be done?

UPDATE: see Note2.

Comment: important for me is the starting time, can i get it also from this list?

Comment: For Linux, use "ps -eo pid,stime" to get the start time listed next to the PID. You can run this command from java in a similar manner as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java

Answer (score 2):

On linux (I am running Ubuntu 14)

```
public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getStartTime(29489));
    }   

    private static String getStartTime(int pid) throws IOException {

        String start = null;        
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec("ps -ewo pid,lstart");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";       
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (line.startsWith(pid+" ")) {
                int firstSpace = line.indexOf(" "); 
                start = line.substring(firstSpace+1);
                break;
            }
        }       
        return start;
    }
}
```

**Output**

Wed Apr 13 21:13:10 2016

Verifying through command line

```
xxx@xxx:~$ ps -ewo pid,lstart | grep 29489
29489 Wed Apr 13 21:13:10 2016
```

Comment: do you know if there is an equivalent command in windows to "ps" ?

Comment: @Gobliins I am not aware of how to achieve that on Windows.