# Using Javacode to get the actual name of the Program that is top

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, jna

I am currently writing a Java Application, that needs to filter the name of the Program whichs UI is front. Sorry for my bad english.
So let's say the Java App is running in Background and I open Windows -> Games -> Minesweeper then i want the App to only tell me "Active: Minesweeper". Without any additional information. Just the name "Minesweeper"

I already tried using JavaNativeAccess but I'm still unfamiliar with it.

Thanks you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the following link which might be of help:

[How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java)