# How to keep track of the applications opened with the amount of time they have been opened using java (WINDOWS 10)

Tags: java, windows, exe, taskmanager, tracker

I am trying to build a java program which runs in the background when the computer is turned on which tracks the activities performed (apps that have been opened and the time) and stores it in a .txt file but im not sure how to do the first part, that is, getting the list of applications that are open and the time they have been opened.

Comment: Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469548/how-to-get-list-of-current-running-application-like-task-manager-except-applicat

Comment: I don't think you could do it with only java, as java is running on a VM you would need some kind of a scripting language to send the data to your java application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of current running application like Task Manager except applications running in background using JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469548/how-to-get-list-of-current-running-application-like-task-manager-except-applicat)