# How to get amount of running exe files from Windows Task Manager

Tags: java, windows

I'm accessing to running exe using below method. But I want to get the count of running exe files. Basically I want to get the count of exe process currently runs. Other than assigning all the process name to a list is there a simple way to obtain the count.

```
public boolean isProcessRunning(String serviceName) {

    try {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // System.out.println(line);
            if (line.startsWith(serviceName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: And what's your problem? What do you see, what do you expect to see, ...? What is `TASKLIST`? ...

Comment: *what's your problem?
I want to get the count of exe process currently runs. Other than assigning all the process name to a list is there a simple way to obtain the count.
*What do you see, what do you expect to see, ...?
I don't know what to use. So currently stuck. 
What is TASKLIST?
Sorry it is assigned to "tasklist"

Comment: Did you try `ProcessHandle.allProcesses().count()` ? See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-retrieve-all-processes-data-of-process-api-in-java-9, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068036/13211030