# How to find and close running Win-Process which is Java app from within other Java app?

Tags: java

There is windows process which is actually a java application (java.exe). I need to close it from within other java application (other running .jar) which is probably will also be named as `java.exe` in windows taskbar.

To do the task we would normally do it this way

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + `java.exe`);
```

But there would be some `java.exe` processes in windows taskbar. So how to find the one I need? In this case it is `forum.jar`.

Actually this jar was started from .bat file (if it makes any difference) - it is `process.bat` as it seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I believe this will help you: [How to get a list of current open windows/process with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) Alternatively, try [jps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jps.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run

```
wmic process where caption="java.exe" get commandline,description,processid
```

to get the list of processes and their associated command line like in your screenshot. Then you get the ID of the command you want to kill and kill it with `taskkill /pid xxx`.

Comment: How did you get command line string from tasklist output? I could get process nane, pid, session name, memory and session number. But to detect the pid which is related to `forum.jar` there should be a way to obtain the command line string from there.

Comment: My bad it does not work, see my edit.