# How to get the Window title from that application processId

Tags: java, process, pid

How can we get the main title of the application from the processId of that application.

Can we use the ProcessHandler to get the window title?

Comment: For which OS do you need an application?

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo can there be a platform-independent solution for this? If not then what would be the different solutions for different platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 9 and later, you can use the `ProcessHandle` class to get information about a running process:

```java
public class PH {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessHandle.allProcesses().forEach(PH::info);
    }

    private static void info(final ProcessHandle processHandle) {
        processHandle.info().user().ifPresent(PH::print);
        processHandle.info().command().ifPresent(PH::print);
        processHandle.info().commandLine().ifPresent(PH::print);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void print(final String s) {
        System.out.print(String.format("%s\t", s));
    }
}
```

Approximate console output:

```
root    /usr/libexec/secd   /usr/libexec/secd   
root    /usr/libexec/trustd /usr/libexec/trustd --agent
user    /usr/libexec/lsd    /usr/libexec/lsd
```

I'm not sure that you will be able to get the title of an application by this way, but you can check another methods of [ProcessHandle.Info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.Info.html) class.

---

Also you can try to use OS-specific utils for getting information about processes:

- `ps -e` for Linux and Mac (you can read more about it [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html))
- `tasklist.exe` for Windows (you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist))

In order to call that commands you can use the next code:

```java
String command = "ps -e";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

// Get the input stream of the command's output
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

---

Actually the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) have been already asked, maybe you will find something useful here.

---

**Example:**

In order to get "window title" of all processes in OS Windows, you can run the next command:

```
tasklist /v /fo list |find /i "window title" |find /v "N/A"
```

It will print something like this:

```bash
...
Window Title: Untitled - Notepad
Window Title: Command Prompt
...
```

It means you can run that command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` as I explained above:

```java
String command = "tasklist /v /fo list |find /i \"window title\" |find /v \"N/A\"";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

// Get the input stream of the command's output
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: But this does not provides the window title.

Comment: @ameerzeya what do you mean "window title"? What is it exactly?

Comment: Example when we open notepad, the window title is shown as "Untitled - Notepad". If we have the processId of notepad, Can we get this String value of the title as "Untitled - Notepad"? @Volodya Lombrozo

Comment: @ameerzeya I've added example, please have a look

Comment: Thank you Volodya , this solution from tasklist works, I am using it in PowerShell as CMD little relatively slower. Do we have equivalent command in Linux or mac also, In Linux, I can see there is the command "ps" but it doesn't seems to have windowtitle as return parameter . @Volodya Lobrozo

Comment: @ameerzeya I believe it would be better to investigate it in a separate question